# Want a tracing font for Montessori Work Sheets

Tags: fonts, page-layout, font-recommendation, education

I am designing Montessori work sheets.

I wanted a Font for tracing for pupils. I googled it and found "**KG Primary Dots** **by Kimberly Geswein**", but when I use this font in my work sheet and printed it, the font was looking **very thick** for tracing.

[image: KG Primary Dots font example]

My question is that could you tell me any font that can fulfill my choice?

Comment: Adding an example image would be really useful, as that may explain what you mean by "very thick"; you should also be a bit more specific about what your requirements are.

Comment: couldn't you print it at 50% black? Also, if your students are still at the point where they're tracing, "thick" is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: ^ Very good idea (50% black or in gray). Aamir, what software are you using to create your worksheets?

Comment: @go-junta i am using Corel Draw x6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I "third" the decision above to use that font in a gray color... but if you want other options, here are a couple!

1. **Trace Font for Kids** (personal use only): http://www.fontspace.com/p-j-cassel/trace-font-for-kids
   [image]
2. **Raleway Dots**: (free for commercial use)... http://www.1001fonts.com/raleway-dots-font.html 
   This is another option, but may not have the "correct" penmanship that you're looking for.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: The only issues I see with these fonts is: 1) The OP will need to add the lines, 2) They aren't much different from his own font for the tracing and 3) the shape of each letter and number is very important (eg. the "a", the "f", etc.)

Comment: Ahh, @go-junta, I assumed the lines were part of the document design and not as part of the font. And I do understand that the shape isn't perfect for penmanship!

Comment: There's a benefit in not having the lines though, they can be added in another color or darker than the text!

Comment: @go-junta i assume that adding lines will no problem for me,

Comment: @acook712 thanks for your kind help, i think "Trace Font for Kids" that you mentioned above is best for my need.

Comment: @Aamirshah Happy to help!